# How to install the Memcache module?

Tags: 6, caching

I'm running Drupal 6 website with AWS.

I have downloaded the [Memcache API and Integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/Memcache) (from the official site).

Do I need to just FTP the files into the memcache module directory and load the admin page and configure it?

What are the exact steps to install the module in Drupal via the module directory?

Comment: The steps are well laid out in [the README](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/memcache/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=6.x-1.x), if you're having a specific problem please edit to indicate what that is. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your developer most likely has more complex release methods in place, so what you can do is probably a temporary solution that he has to improve. You should definitely test the module on another environment before putting it on a production server. However, in its simplest form it will be enough to put the module folder and its contents in the sites/all/modules/contrib folder (or without contrib if that isn't present). Then go to the admin interface and enable the module in the modules page.

Comment: It probably won't do anything unless you make changes to settings.php though: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/memcache/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=6.x-1.x

Comment: And that ^^ :)
My answer is basically a generic module solution for any module without specific needs. Memcache is definitely a more complex one that needs a lot more work and testing. I would definitely recommend not just doing this straight on production without knowing what you are doing in Drupal.

Comment: Amen to that :)